# SQL server ERROR Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

Can't understand what's wrong in this SQL query:

```
USE [My_db]
GO

SELECT ItemId
      ,Subject
      ,CreatedOn
  FROM ItemBase AS e
      INNER JOIN ItemExtensionBase AS p
      ON e.ItemId = p.ItemId
GO
```

**Error:**

```
 Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
 Ambiguous column name 'ItemId'.
```

`ItemId` column exist in both tables.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - but it doesn't match your SQL - You say they're both tables - but that means you're not mapping ItemID to LeadID - so where is LeadID coming from? You won't get that message unless you're actually using LeadID.

Comment: @dbmitch , sorry for typos; yes it should be 'ItemId'. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
USE [My_db]
GO

SELECT e.ItemId
      ,Subject
      ,CreatedOn
  FROM ItemBase AS e
      INNER JOIN ItemExtensionBase AS p
      ON e.ItemId = p.ItemId
GO
```

You need to tell it which table to take the itemid field from

Answer (score 3):

Use `e.ItemId` or `p.ItemId`:

```
USE [My_db]
GO

SELECT e.ItemId
      ,Subject
      ,CreatedOn
  FROM ItemBase AS e
      INNER JOIN ItemExtensionBase AS p
      ON e.ItemId = p.ItemId
GO
```